# Python based desktop application starts very slow due to 400 excel rows to display

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

I am creating a Python based desktop  application. Its source is an excel file on sharepoint, with 4 sheets: 1st sheet has 300 rows,
2nd sheet - 55,
3rd  sheet - 30
4th sheet - 10 rows.
For each row, images are uploaded from another folder, matching them based an unique number, hence 400 images, 'png' format.
The app starts very slowly, it takes minutes to open. How to make it faster?  I would prefer to upload the whole information from the beginning and not to use lazy loading.
What other improvements I could bring for it to start faster? Is the latency something that is normal under the above conditions?

I tried lazy loading but it's not desired for my app. Also , app freezes when switching tabs with lazy loading

Comment: Use a profiler to find performance bottlenecks. Measure, don't guess.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?